# How to simulate or solve $n$-legged manometer without solving Euler's equations?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, computational-physics

Consider a typical manometer tube but with $n$-legs, different heights at the initial time. Is there any way to solve it numerically or analytically without solving NS or Euler's equations? For example for two legged one we know it is an SHM oscillation with $T= 2 \pi \sqrt\frac{l}{g} $

Comment: It can be done by expressing the total mechanical energy of the fluid as the sum of its potential plus kinetic energy, and, for an inviscid fluid, setting the time derivative of that equal to zero.

Comment: @ChetMiller But how do I solve for individual accelerations.. Like you said if I try

PE = 0.5* mg(h1(t)+h2(t)+h3(t)...hn(t))
KE=0.5*rho*(h1(t)*v1(t)^2+h2(t)*v2(t)^2...+hn(t)*vn(t)^2 )

D(PE+KE)/Dt=0 = 0.5*mg(v1(t)+v2(t)...+vn(t))+0.5*rho*(v1(t)^3+v2(t)^3..vn(t)^3)+rho*(h1(t)v1(t)a1(t)+h2(t)v2(t)a2(t)....+hn(t)vn(t)an(t))=0

finally, we need  h1(t),h2(t).. hn(t).. for which we need a1(t),a2(t).. How do I go forward?

Comment: Have you tried Bernoullis equation? Its derived from Navier-Stokes and is used usually in tube and manometer-type problems.